# How to get ride of x=undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

When I get the user inputs and click on submit, it is showing x=undefined. How to resolve this issue ?
Here is my code. or http://jsfiddle.net/L9LKc/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JS Assignment</title>
        <script>
        function changeCheckBox() {
     try {

         var max = document.myform.check.length;
         var count = 0;

         for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
             if (document.myform.check[i].checked == true) {
                 count++;
                 serNoChecked = i;
             }
         }
         if (count == 1) {
             for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                 if (document.myform.check[i].checked == false) {
                     document.myform.check[i].disabled = true;
                 }
             }
         } else if (count == 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                 document.myform.check[i].disabled = false;
             }
         }

         if (null == max) return false;
         if (count == 0) {
             return true;
         } else if (count > 0) {
             return false;
         }

     } catch (e) {
         alert(e.message);
     }
 }
 </script>
 <script>
    function arith(op) {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value,10);
    var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value,10);
    var newVal;
    if (op == "Addition") {
        newVal = n1+n2;
    } else if (op == "Subtraction") {
        newVal = n1-n2;
    } else if (op == "Multiplication") {
        newVal = n1*n2;
    } else if (op == "Division") {
        newVal = n1/n2;
    }

    var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
    demoP.innerHTML="x=" + newVal;
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body background="photo.jpg">
        <h3>Simple JavaScript Arithmetic Operations</h3>
        <form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return arith()">
        Value 1 <input type ="text" id="num1"> <br><br>
        Value 2 <input type="text" id="num2"> <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Addition" id="check1" onclick="changeCheckBox(this.value)">Addition<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Subtraction" id="check2" onclick="changeCheckBox(this.value)">Subtraction<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Multiplication" id="check3" onclick="changeCheckBox(this.value)">Multiplication<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Division" id="check4" onclick="changeCheckBox(this.value)">Division<br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `op` is `undefined` because you are not passing when you call `onsubmit="return arith()`

Comment: Ya modified. Now It is processing, But I cant get the output..Can you please check it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of errors, the most important is you never assign `op`. I fixed it (quick and dirty):

```
var op;
function changeCheckBox(val) {
    try {
        var i;
        var max = document.myform.check.length;
        var count = 0;
        op = val;

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (document.myform.check[i].checked === true) {
                count++;
                serNoChecked = i;
            }
        }
        if (count === 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                if (document.myform.check[i].checked === false) {
                    document.myform.check[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        } else if (count === 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                document.myform.check[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (null === max) return false;
        if (count === 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (count > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

function arith() {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value, 10);
    var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value, 10);
    var newVal;
    if (op == "Addition") {
        newVal = n1 + n2;
    } else if (op == "Subtraction") {
        newVal = n1 - n2;
    } else if (op == "Multiplication") {
        newVal = n1 * n2;
    } else if (op == "Division") {
        newVal = n1 / n2;
    }

    var demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
    demoP.innerHTML = "x=" + newVal;
    return false;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qr7U8/

Answer (score 1):

"return arith()", so no "op" value passed in arith(op), and op===undefined.

You need to get the right value for op:

```
function getCheckedValue() {
    var checks = document.myform.check;

    for (var i = 0, len = checks.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked) return checks[i].value;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And in  function arith(op):

```
function arith(op) {

    op = op || getCheckedValue();
        ....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/L9LKc/8/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because if you click directly on Submit without checking any operation, it will not calculate `x`.

Add

```
else
{
    alert("Check at least one operation");
}
```

part in your if else.

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9LKc/2/) . So it will show an alert if any operation is not selected and not give an error of undefined.

Hope this helps.

P.S: You should make them radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

And you are calling method `arith()` without passing parameter to it. So op is null every time. Hence its showing alert.

Comment: Now, it is showing only the alert if I click on any checkboxes and click submit

Comment: yes. Its because you are calling method arith() without passing op parameter. Change that. @DineshKumar

Comment: Now, it is not showing the alert. It is processing, But I cant get the output..Can you please check it ?